# How to handler form submits in team city plugin development jsp

Tags: java, jsp, teamcity

Im Learning how to write TeamCity plugins with Java JSP.

I want to have a form that excepts text information and uses it for data processing.

The problem Im facing is that I get a 404 when I click the submit button.

Controller

```
public class ServerConfigGeneralController extends BaseFormXmlController {
      public ServerConfigGeneralController(@NotNull SBuildServer server,
                                           @NotNull WebControllerManager webControllerManager) {
        super(server);
        webControllerManager.registerController("/admin/", this);
      }

      @Override
      @Nullable
      protected ModelAndView doGet(@NotNull final HttpServletRequest request, @NotNull final HttpServletResponse response) {
          System.out.println("######In Model and View########");
        return null;
      }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Element xmlResponse) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("######In Do Post########");

    }

}
```

Jsp

```
<html>
    <h1>Consul Key Value settings</h1>
   <body>

      <form action = "ServerConfigGeneralController" method = "post">
         URL: <input type = "text" name = "url">
         <br />
         Port: <input type = "text" name = "port" />
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

xml config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"
       default-autowire="constructor">

       <bean class="com.demoDomain.teamcity.demoPlugin.AppServer"></bean>
       <bean id="MyListener" class="com.demoDomain.teamcity.demoPlugin.MyListener"></bean>
       <bean id="TestAdminPage" class="com.demoDomain.teamcity.demoPlugin.TestAdminPage"></bean>
       <bean id ="ServerConfigGeneralController" class="com.demoDomain.teamcity.demoPlugin.ServerConfigGeneralController"></bean>
</beans>
```

I was hoping that do Post would be called and the Sys out would be printed on the team city server console.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve it.

I need to get the form action to match the URL registered by the controller.

```
<form action = "/admin/consul.html" method = "post">
```

In Controller

```
manager.registerController("/admin/consul.html", this);
```

Thanks Any way